# Web Audio API - Getting the current offset in a song & onstarted event for a source

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm playing a segment of a music track using a source in the Web Audio API.

```
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

source.start(when, offset, duration);
```

I know that there is an event listener that I can use when the source has finished playing, `source.onended`. Is there an event listener that I can use when the source starts? e.g. `source.onstarted`?

Furthermore, can at any point get what part of the track is currently playing from a source? Or perhaps even from the audioCtx?

e.g. `source.getCurrentOffset(); // 0:21`

I would like to avoid my current strategy of starting a setTimeout when the source starts as it's not accurate.

**Example**

```
source.start(when, offset, duration);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("The track has started!");
}, 1000 * when);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could always `start(0)` an other node and `stop(when)` it, and listen to its `onended` event, but I'm not sure you'll get more precision. But actually, why do you need more precision than `setTimeout` can offer you ? Is that for another AudioContext's method ? Then can't you also call this method using audio_ctx scheduling ? And otherwise, I really don't see what can need so much precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but the source starts exactly when you told it to: at time `when`.

And currently there's no way to determine where in the buffer the source is playing.  People have asked for this feature, but nothing has been done about it in the spec.  The returned time will always be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to trigger an event when the source starts playing, not when it’s created. You could assume that I don’t know what “when” is, or if that’s not possible then assume that I cannot use setTimeout.

Comment: I understand why you don't know `when` is, since you set it.  But currently, there's no way to know, so the `setTimeout` is probably the best you can do, assuming the source does actually start playing.  Adding an `onstarted` event will require a spec change.

Answer (score 0):

You got context.currentTime() But that doesn't help you. With setTimeout you should be fine though. you can get the length of a buffer with myArrayBuffer.duration. You can as well use Date() when started and determine with another Date() how long it has been played.

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like this:

```
function my_start(when, offset, duration, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        source.start(0, offset, duration);
        callback();
    }, when);
}

function onStartedCallback() {
    console.log("The track has started!");
}

my_start(when, offset, duration, onStartedCallback);
```

I would suggest even extending the `source` prototype, but I know that is usually frowned upon - as you may overwrite something.
Also, for more accuracy, you could use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for timing.